# How can I store data from a while-loop in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I Need to store data I gathered via Scanner from a .txt file with a while-loop. The lines in the .txt contain an x-, y-, z-coordinate and a c-value.
I managed to split the lines from the .txt and converted them into numbers but I can't acces them outside the loop to work with them from there. I want to use the "x-" and "y-"coordinates and the c-value to be used in the two dimensional Array "z65".

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;  
import gdi.ct.CtImage ;

public class CtViewer {  
 public static void main(String[] args)   
   throws java.io.FileNotFoundException    
 {

  int x;  
  int y;  
  int z;  
  int c;  
  int xValue;  
  int yValue;  
  int zValue;  
  int cValue;

  int [] [] [] ct = new int [204] [204] [139];

  for ( x = 0; x < 204; x++) {  
   for ( y = 0; y < 204; y++) {  
    for ( z = 0; z < 139; z++) {  
     ct[x][y][z] =  -1000; }}}  
  System.out.println(ct [0] [0] [0]);  
  System.out.println(ct [0] [0] [1]);

  File cTxt = new File("CT-Chest.txt");  
  Scanner readTxt = new Scanner(cTxt);

  while(readTxt.hasNextLine()) {  
   String i = readTxt.nextLine();

   String [] out = i.split(" ");

   xValue = Integer.parseInt(out[0]);  
   yValue =Integer.parseInt(out[1]);  
   zValue= Integer.parseInt(out[2]);  
   cValue =Integer.parseInt(out[3]);


   x =xValue;  
   y=yValue;  
   z=zValue;  
   c = cValue;  
   System.out.println(x+ "" +y+"" +z+ ""+c);    //Works 'till     here.  
   ct [x] [y][z] = c;


  }  
   System.out.println(x+""+y);  
  int[] [] z65 = new int [x] [y];  
  CtImage cI = new CtImage(z65);







 }  
 }
```

Comment: What values have `x`, `y` and `z`? They should be between `0 <= x < 204`, `0 <= y < 204` and `0 <= x < 139` to can do `ct [x] [y][z] = c;`

Comment: Correct. The values are as described by you.

Answer (score 0):

you are over writing your loop variables.   make it like this

```
  x =xValue;  //delete all this
 y=yValue;  
 z=zValue;  
 c = cValue;/// to here
System.out.println(x+ "" +y+"" +z+ ""+c);    //Works 'till     here.  
ct [xValue] [yValue][zValue] = cValue;
```

this is how i was able to do it:

```
int[][][] ct = new int[204][204][139];
    for (int x = 0; x < 204; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 204; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < 139; z++) {
                ct[x][y][z] = -1000;
            }
        }
    }
    File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("CT-Chest.txt").getFile());
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
    lines.stream().filter(s->!s.trim().isEmpty()).forEach(s->{
        String[] split = s.split(" ");
        ct[Integer.parseInt(split[0])][Integer.parseInt(split[1])][Integer.parseInt(split[2])]=Integer.parseInt(split[3]);
    });
    System.out.println(ct[5][8][99]);
```

and the contents of the file i created:

> 5 8 99 2
>   6 203 138 2000
>   203 1 88 135

the output of the program is 2.

is it possible that you are trying to use in another method? `ct` and all of the values read from the file will be available from that point on.  i get the lines from the file a little different but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: actually it's outside the loop so those shoudnt exist

Comment: It still won't let me acces the values from outside of the loop.

Comment: It tells me my variables X and y for the z65 array at the bottom are not initialized

Comment: 1 problem i just noticed. `int[] [] z65 = new int [x] [y];   CtImage cI = new CtImage(z65);` doesent use the ct array where we just put all the data WHY? the code you provided doesn't even then use the array.is the idea to create an image of DImention X,Y and the values of C from Z=1? you don't do any of that. you do attempt to create an int array of size X,Y but you don't put any data in there.

Comment: I changed the Code a Little in the hopes of getting it to work:

Comment: can you update your original post with your current code

Answer (score 0):

If anybody needs a solution for this exact Problem in the future, here is what I worked out.

```
        import java.io.File;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.util.regex.Pattern;
        import gdi.ct.CtImage;

        public class CtViewer {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {

                int x;
                int y;
                int z;
                int c;
                int[][][] ct = new int[204][204][139];

                for (x = 0; x < 204; x++) {
                    for (y = 0; y < 204; y++) {
                        for (z = 0; z < 139; z++) {
                            ct[x][y][z] = -1000;
                        }
                    }
                }

                File cTxt = new File("CT-Chest.txt");
                Scanner readTxt = new Scanner(cTxt);
                int[][] z65 = new int[204][204];
                do {
                    String i = readTxt.nextLine();
                    String[] out = i.split(" ");

                    int xValue = Integer.parseInt(out[0]);
                    int yValue = Integer.parseInt(out[1]);
                    int zValue = Integer.parseInt(out[2]);
                    ct[xValue][yValue][zValue] = Integer.parseInt(out[3]);
                    if (zValue == 65) {
                        xValue = Integer.parseInt(out[0]);
                        yValue = Integer.parseInt(out[1]);
                        zValue = Integer.parseInt(out[2]);
                        z65[xValue][yValue] = Integer.parseInt(out[3]);
                    }
                }
                while (readTxt.hasNextLine());
                CtImage cI = new CtImage(z65);


                readTxt.close();
            }


        }
```